# Add new TabBarItems in UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an application which has a `UITabbarController` with only One `TabBarItem` in it i.e. "Home".

Now the problem is while I am in my Home Tab bar Item Can i Add More TabbarItem's with different `ViewControllers` to my existing `UITabbarcontroller`.

Here is more elaborated example:

I have only One "Home Tab". I called a service on Home Tab and then server said there must also be `ViewController1` and `ViewController2` available on the `TabBar`. Then can I create it on run time. If Yes can any one describe how!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   NewViewController* vc1 = [[NewViewController alloc] init];

   vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
   vc1.tabBarItem.title = @"Title";

   NSMutableArray* controllers = [NSMutableArray arraywithArray :tabBarController.viewControllers];
   [controllers addObject:vc1];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Got it. Perfect. Working like a charm. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new NSMutableArray with a copy of the existing views, then tack your new view on the end and set the Tab Controller views to be the new copy. So if you're in your existing 'single' ViewController:

```
ViewController *newView = [[ViewController alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[views addObject:newView];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = views;
```